# Selenium - drop down box query

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selector

I'm currently using Selenium (c#) to automate a grid functionality, which adds campaigns to a table.

So prior to selecting a random drop down value in integers. I need to input a a campaignName, and a campaignId. I have a dropdown option which entitles me to add x times the campaignName which increments that campaignName+1 so if I select 76 in the dropdown  menu I would have campaignName+76  so campaignName76.

No I have a method which is executed prior, this generates a random value. 52 for instance. Now this value is stored in a field _NumberValue. And then 52 campaignNames are created.

This is _NumberValue is referenced in another function later, now the option drop down increments in 10, 20, 30, 40.

If I have 27 I need the selector to select 30 on the menu. This will display the count on the rows, which I assert matches the _NumberValue and the CampaignNumbers.

Is there a simpler way to write this than just using conditional flow?

```
   private static void DisplayCorrectNumberOfRows(IWebDriver driver)
            {
                var value = CampaignBulkValue;
                WaitElements.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[@id='PageSizeDropdown_popup']"));

                if (value <= 10)
                {
                    LinkHelper.ClickLink(By.Id("PageSizeDropdown"));
                    TextBoxHelper.InputText(By.Id("PageSizeDropdown"), "10"); 
else if (value == 11 || value <= 20)
            {
                LinkHelper.ClickLink(By.Id("PageSizeDropdown"));
                TextBoxHelper.InputText(By.Id("PageSizeDropdown"), "20");
```

etc/

Can anyone recommend a cleaner approach then just using conditional flow?

It looks gross but I did this quickly!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
private static void DisplayCorrectNumberOfRows(IWebDriver driver)
{
    var value = CampaignBulkValue;
    WaitElements.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[@id='PageSizeDropdown_popup']"));

    // maybe you want to throw an exception here when value is 0
    // or you can ignore it and set it as 10 :
    //  var pageSize = Math.Min(Math.Ceiling(value / 10.0) * 10, 10);
    var pageSize = Math.Ceiling(value / 10.0) * 10
    LinkHelper.ClickLink(By.Id("PageSizeDropdown"));
    TextBoxHelper.InputText(By.Id("PageSizeDropdown"), pageSize .ToString());
}
```